# Find an explicit expression for $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(z^2+1)^n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, power-series

> Let $z \in \mathbb{C}$, discuss the convergence of $$g(z)= \displaystyle\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac{1}{(z^2+1)^n}$$ and find an explicit expression for $g(z)$.

By the ratio test, I found that $z$ must satisfies that $|z^2+1|>1$. Then by geometric series, we claim that $g(z) = \dfrac{1}{1-\dfrac{1}{z^2+1}} = \dfrac{z^2+1}{z^2}$.

Is my answer correct? What can I say about the radius of convergence since I only got $|z^2+1|>1$?

Comment: That is not a power series.

Comment: I do not find any mistake. The convergent domain is $C  = \{ z | |z^2 + 1| > 1  \}$.

Comment: @MartinR Right, thank you. I just imply the theorem without thinking

Comment: @Martin R But if I let $Z= \dfrac{1}{z^2+1}$, I can imply the theorem right?

Comment: put $u=z^2+1$ and then it becomes a power series, so the reasoning is correct

Answer (score 3):

Your argument is fine. The only mistake in what you wrote is to talk about *radius of convergence*. This is not a power series and so there is no reason to expect  the region of convergence to be a disk.

Note that the prompt you were given says "discuss the convergence". As you correctly stated, the series is convergent for $z$ such that $|z^2+1|>1$. That would be the outside of the [lemniscate](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=polar+plot+%7C%28r%5E2cos%282theta%29%2B1%29%5E2%2B%282r%5E2cos%28theta%29sin%28theta%29%29%5E2%3D1)

[image]

Comment: No, that's not the right region.  Note that it must be symmetric about the origin.  Its boundary is actually a lemniscate.

Comment: Yes, my bad. Stupid me did $|z+1|>1$.